# The grammatic name and function for "what he did" is bad

Tags: grammar

The full sentence is:

> What he did is bad.

So I need the grammatical name and function for "what he did".

Answer (score 3):

> *What he did is bad.*

*What he did* is a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction, functioning as subject of the sentence.

It's called a fused relative construction because the single word *what* combines or fuses the functions of head and relative word to give the equivalent of *the thing which*.

The meaning is like that of the non-fused *The thing which he did is bad*.

Comment: Why do you say like that of instead of is the same as?